# GitLab runners hanging after job is finished

Tags: gitlab, openshift, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We are currently in the process of migrating our CI/CD pipelines to GitLab. For testing purposes we are using a runner deployed on OpenShift 4 using the GitLab Runner operator. Using the default configuration for now (we are still in a very early stage) we are able to spin up runners normally and without issues, however we are noticing long delays between jobs. For example a build job normally takes about 2 minutes for the actual build to take place, takes almost 8 minutes in total as a job to finish. This happens even after the job has successfully finished (as evident by the logs). This in turn means that there are long delays between jobs of a single pipeline.

I took a look at the configuration properties of the runner but I am unable to figure out whether we have something misconfigured. For reference we are using GitLab CE version 13.12.15 and the Runner in  question is running version 15.0.0.

Does anyone know how to mitigate this problem?